Stackexchange API to fetch saved posts across all stackexchange network
I want to fetch my saved posts from across stackexchange network that I have joined, is it possible? I have read the documentation on the api.stackexchange.com and it seems the api is intended for specific network at a time

Well, the bigger issue is that there is no API to fetch saved posts at all. The GET /users/{ids}/favorites API endpoint is deprecated. What is now saves used to be called "favourites" (and also bookmarks) but that feature is entirely superseded by Saves. And saves are not exposed via the API.
You have to resort to scraping the website to get your Saves. See How can I download my "saves" lists? which has some rough workarounds. That can serve as inspiration for how to scrape the data.
You can otherwise find all your accounts from the GET /users/{ids}/associated endpoint. Note that it takes your network profile ID. It will return all accounts you have on all network sites.
